# Strapi - Failed to upload image file with Google Cloud Storage provider

Tags: strapi

I followed https://www.npmjs.com/package/strapi-upload-google-storage to setup Strapi File Upload plugin with Google Cloud Storage provider. When I upload a cover image to a post and save. It failed with "TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON".

[2019-02-08T17:54:02.097Z] debug GET 53771798877e88bccc275e15ba634a83.svg (1 ms)
TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    at JSON.stringify ()
    at EventEmitter.stringify (/Users/gwowen/workspace-node/adtalem-cms/node_modules/strapi/node_modules/fast-safe-stringify/index.js:5:15)
    at EventEmitter.asJson (/Users/gwowen/workspace-node/adtalem-cms/node_modules/strapi/node_modules/pino/pino.js:161:22)
    at EventEmitter.pinoWrite (/Users/gwowen/workspace-node/adtalem-cms/node_modules/strapi/node_modules/pino/pino.js:215:16)
    at EventEmitter.LOG (/Users/gwowen/workspace-node/adtalem-cms/node_modules/strapi/node_modules/pino/lib/tools.js:93:10)
    at update (/Users/gwowen/workspace-node/adtalem-cms/plugins/content-manager/controllers/ContentManager.js:83:18)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)

Is this a known bug or is there something not configured right?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no correct link to the source code for that package so it's hard to tell what the issue might be. Judging from the readme with the npm package, you need to supply a piece of json. If I combine that information with your call stack, you might have pasted the wrong piece of json.

You need to check the json you pasted in the config in strapi for circular references and double check you haven't missed anything in your configuration.

Comment: The json is too long so I change it a little bit:

`{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "***",
  "private_key_id": "***",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "client_email": "mobilesolutions@adtalem-cms.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "client_id": "108795273235518932173",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/***"
}
`

This is the right json, right?

Comment: Pretty straight forward flat json... Might be a bug in the provider. You know you can pretty easily roll your own provider? Day before yesterday I wrote my own provider for azure storage and it took me about 2 hours to get it all done, based on the aws provider in strapi itself. You can check it out [here](https://github.com/sylvaingirardbe/strapi-provider-upload-azure).